# Как умножить значение инпута и прибавить к нему другой инпут?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как можно **прибавить** значение из input plus к результату умножения значения из input argument ?

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var argument = $('input[name="argument"]')
      , result = $('input[name="result"]')
      , multiplier = 4;
    argument.on('input', function() {
      result.val($(this).val() * multiplier);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="plus"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
```

Comment: умножить - прибавить - когнитивный диссонанс

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я не знаю, как это сделать. Если я добавлю в строку $(this).val() * multiplier); + $('input[name="argument"]').val() то ничего не проиходит, а по другому я не знаю как.

Comment: Научитесь уже добавлять метку `[jquery]` в вопрос при его создании, **пожалуйста**! (не только персонально, а ко всем использующим эту библиотеку в коде вопроса, кто это прочтет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var argument = $('input[name="argument"]')
      , result = $('input[name="result"]')
      , plus = $('input[name="plus"]')
      , multiplier = 4;
      
    argument.on('input', recalc);
    plus.on('input', recalc);
    
    function recalc() {
       result.val((+argument.val() * multiplier) + (+plus.val()));
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="plus"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
```